# Html relative paths using period

Tags: html, relative-path

I'm confused as to when the following are used and what they mean, for example in the src attribute of an img tag.

I know / means 'current directory' and ../ means 'up one directory'

```
.   Current Directory?  <a href="." />  
./  Current Directory   <img src="./image.png" />  
/   Root directory      <img src="/image.png" />  
../ Up one directory    <img src="../image.png" />
```

What is the difference between ./image.png and /image.png

**Updated**: / means root directory of the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` means starting from the root directory. Whereas `./` is the current directory, though I'm not sure there's any need for it (unless you're planning on appending to a `PATH` in Linux systems... happy to be wrong about that one).

Comment: Yeah, It's my understanding that `./image.png` would be the same as just `image.png`

Comment: cool. I've inherited some code that had ./ for referencing images so that is where the question comes from

Answer (score 1):

`./image.png` will grab image.png relative to your current location. Calling ./image.png on `domain.tld/site/page.html` will look for the image at `domain.tld/site/image.png`

`/image.png` will look for the image in the root of your site. `domain.tld/image.png`

---

You could also use things like `../images/image.png`. If this was used on `domain.tld/site/page.html`, the browser would load the image from `domain.tld/images/image.png`

Answer (score 0):

The / means the root directory. Use   . For the current directory.